# Kibana: Show values on Y axis as percentage

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I want to visualize the amount of correct auto-responses my system sent in regards to the percentage of questions it has already learned. 
So my idea was to filter all my test-results where a boolean field `didSendCorrectAutoResponse` is true, make the bucket on the x axis over a field called `learnPercentage` and on the y axis simply take the count as a metric.

The only problem with this is that the values on the y-axis are absolute and only count the number of responses sent but I want it to show it as a percentage of the total number of tests per percentage learned.

Here is how I defined my chart:
[image: Chart definition]

I can calculate the total number of test-cases for each percentage learned with this `learnPercentage: 100 && strategy.keyword: "sum"` (it only counts them for 100% questions learned, but the number of tests for each percentage is the same).

So what I want on the y-axis is not the plain count but `count / totalNumberOfTestCases`

---

**edit:** 
In order for you to better understand what I need here is what I do with my system:

Lets say I have 100 known questions my system can learn. And I have 2500 test questions. Now I do the following:

1. Let my system learn none of the known questions
2. Ask the 2500 test questions
3. Save how many questions have been correctly answered (let's say 600)
4. Save this test result in elastic

Repeat with 10 questions learned:

1. Let my system learn 10% of the known questions
2. Ask the 2500 test questions
3. Save how many questions have been correctly answered (let's say 590)
4. Save this result in elastic

Repeat with 20 questions learned...

Now I want to plot how many questions have been correctly answered in each learning step:

- 600 at 0%
- 590 at 10%
- 900 at 20%
- ...

But instead of showing these absolute numbers I want 600/2500, 590/2500 etc on the y-axis.

Comment: have you tried pie chart?

Comment: I don't want a pie chart. I want to see the learning curve. Also a pie chart would not solve my problem at all since the total number of tests per percentage learned would still not be included

Comment: use Percentiles?

Comment: percentile on which field?

Comment: please provide me some stub data..

Comment: edited question

Answer (score 0):

For Visualizing your Y axis in percentage if it is not already in, You should first create a scripted field for your favorite column and then visualize that scripted field in kibana.
check the photos; in scripted field code, the removed part is your column name.
[image]

[image]

Comment: This does not help. I don't want to show a field formatted as percentage, I want the value of `Count` (the metric on the Y axis) which is computed by Kiabana to be a percentage value